# Why aren't updates to URDF files being recognized?

Tags: ros

I am using cartographer_ros.  I have a URDF file in ~/catkin_ws/src/cartographer_ros/cartographer_ros/urdf.  I am trying to update this URDF file, but even when I rebuild the workspace by deleting the build_isolated folder and then running catkin_make_isolated --install --use-ninja, RVIZ behaves as if I'm still using the old version of that URDF file when I run roslaunch cartographer_ros jackal_VLP16_kvhIMU_2D.launch.  I have to actually create a new URDF file with a different filename and point to that in the launch file for any changes to take effect.  This isn't normal, is it?

Comment: I would't expect that, no. Are you sure that you have closed all nodes including the ROS master node `roscore`?

Comment: Looks like you are not loading / publishing the transformations defined in the file. Could you check this?